# Aeson Parser Returning 'Nothing' for Array field

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to extract the 3rd element of the 'path' key from the following JSON input:

```
{
  "certname": "some.server.name",
  "path": [
    "networking",
    "interfaces",
    "eth0",
    "bindings",
    0,
    "address"
  ],
  "name": "networking",
  "value": "192.168.1.1",
  "environment": "develop"
}
```

but all I get is 'Nothing' when running this program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Monad        (mzero)
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import           Data.Text
import qualified Data.Vector          as V

data HostNicIp =
  HostNicIp { hniHost :: !Text
            , hniNic  :: !Text
            , hniIp   :: !Text
            } deriving Show

instance FromJSON HostNicIp where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    HostNicIp
      <$> (o .: "certname")
      <*> fmap (V.! 2) (o .: "path")
      <*> (o .: "value" )
  parseJSON _  = mzero

main :: IO ()
main = print ( decode demo :: Maybe HostNicIp )

demo :: ByteString
demo = "{\"certname\":\"some.server.name\",\"path\":[\"networking\",\"interfaces\",\"eth0\",\"bindings\",0,\"address\"],\"name\":\"networking\",\"value\":\"192.168.1.1\",\"environment\":\"develop\"}"
```

Commenting `hniNic` out and its related logic makes the program parse everything else

**Edit:**

Running this with `eitherDecode` makes it complain about encountering a `Number` instead of `Text`

```
*Main> eitherDecode demo :: Either String HostNicIp 
Left "Error in $.path[4]: expected Text, encountered Number"
```

while the raw `Object` seems to be parsed OK

```
*Main> eitherDecode demo :: Either String Object
Right (fromList [("certname",String "some.server.name"),("path",Array [String "networking",String "interfaces",String "eth0",String "bindings",Number 0.0,String "address"]),("environment",String "develop"),("value",String "192.168.1.1"),("name",String "networking")])
```

Is it possible to use Aeson for heterogeneous lists? How should I approach this?

Comment: Try to run the parser with `eitherDecode` to see the error message.

Comment: Thanks @erdeszt, it now shows

`Left "Error in $.path[4]: expected Text, encountered Number"`

which refers to the following:

`("path",Array [String "networking",String "interfaces",String "eth0",String "bindings",Number 0.0,String "address"])`

I'm not sure why it would fail here.

Comment: It can't convert the array under `path` into a `Vector` because it holds different types(Text vs Number). I don't have a ghci at hand right now but I can get back in a few hours if you still have no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fmap (V.! 2) (o .: "path")
```

`o .: "path"` here must have type `Parser (Vector Text)` but the array you give contains a number.

Instead, do not decode the array, i.e., use `o .: "path"` at type `Parser Value`, and then destruct the value explicitly by pattern matching or using `withArray`. Then given an `Array` (i.e., `Vector Value`, which is heterogeneous) you can get the second element `(V.! 2)` and convert it to `Text` (by pattern matching, with `withText`, or with `parseJSON`).

```
(o .: "path") >>= withArray "Path info" (parseJSON . (V.! 2))
```